# Excel - display last filled cell on blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to create a formula to pull data from a blank cell into the last cell with printed text. Here is the target output:

[image]

Currently I am using `=INDEX(M4:M16,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((M4:M16<>0),0),0))` which displays as this (below) - Should I be using a different method to try to achieve this or am I just setting some of the numbers wrong?

[image]

Many Thanks.

Comment: So there are never consecutive non-blank entries in the Source column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(INDEX(M:M,ROW()+1)="","",INDEX(M:M,MAX(IF((M:M<>"")*(ROW(M:M)<ROW()),ROW(M:M)))))`

This will not throw the data for the final value, since it triggers if column M shows data in the next row.
The logic for showing the last value is not defined and both your data and example try show different outcomes for that.

Comment: Just one instance of that formula has to process more than 3 million cells.

Comment: `=IF(INDEX(M:M,ROW()+1)="","",INDEX(M:M,MAX(IF((M$1:INDEX(M:M,ROW())<>"")*(ROW(M$1:INDEX(M:M,ROW()))<ROW()),ROW(M$1:INDEX(M:M,ROW()))))))` would fix thatand is still dynamic, but makes it a lot less understandable. Also this is done on my Android phone, so calculation issue is not really a thing in the first place.